# Showing the intersection of infinitely many open sets is closed

Tags: analysis

I have a problem I'm trying to solve which reads,

Construct a countable infinity of open sets $A_n \subset \mathbb{C}$, $n$=1,2,3..., such that their intersection $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is not open.

My thought process is as follows:

Consider a set $$A_n=\{z=x+iy:x^2+y^2<\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
That is, $A_1$ is the collection of all complex numbers whose magnitude is less than 1.  Then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ = $\{0\}$ which is closed.

I feel that this proof is flawed somehow.  Is it really okay to go from having a sets of imaginary numbers to them all simply containing the real number $0$?  Hopefully I'm getting my point across.  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: "Not open" is not at all the same thing as "closed".  However, it is also true that $\{0\}$ is not open.

Comment: Yes I was thinking this as I posted it, thanks for reminding me.  But $\{0\}$ is closed, and therefore not open, yes?

Comment: There are two subsets of $\mathbb C$ that are both closed and open: $\mathbb C$ itself and the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having doubts about your own proof can be hard to work through, so let me play the adversary for you.

I don't believe that your set contains ONLY the element $0$, I think it also contains the element $\gamma$, which lies on the circle of radius $\epsilon>0$ about the origin. How about you show me why that element CAN'T be in your set?

Also, for my peace of mind, lets change your sets to be the following:
$$
A_n = \{z=x+iy : x^2+y^2<\frac{1}{n^2},n\in \mathbb{N}\}
$$

Comment: Well, since the rationals are dense, I can find a number $q$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{q} < \epsilon$.  Since this is the case, there are some elements of $A_n$ which don't contain $\gamma$, hence $\gamma$ can't be in the set.

Comment: There you have it; the only possible element in the set is 0, and you know that 0 is definitely there. Thus the intersection is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, testing my hypothesis helped me greatly!